# how to traverse through a for loop

Tags: loops, if-statement, python-3.x

I have a list of items, I want to be able to go through the list. start at index [0] if the item is in the board, add 1 to the index and keep going, if its not assign that value of x to computermove and break outside the loop . with the way I have it, the computermove  is "b2" even though its in the list, shouldn't it add 1 to the index and loop back around, I don't understand that

```
list=["b2", "a1", "c3", "a3", "c1", "a2", "b3", "b1", "c2"]
board = {0:'b2', 1:' ', 2:' ',
         3:' ', 4:'a1', 5:' ',
         6:' ', 7:' ', 8:'c3',
        }



for x in list:
    if x in board:
        x = x+1
    else:
        computermove= x 
        break
```

Comment: You seem to know in the beginning of the loop that the for loop loops over elements, not indexes. Why are you later trying to use `x` as if it was an index?

Comment: Also, `x in board` checks if `x` is in the keys of `board`.

Comment: but isnt that the only way ill be able to add 1 to it, if it was an index? how would i implement it so it checks the values of board?

Comment: You should just let your loop handle that. e.g. use `continue`, or check for the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to not understand how a for loop works.
You should not be increasing indexes manually(and `x` is not an index anyway), but let the for loop do that for you.

Your other problem is that `x in board` checks if `x` is in the keys of `board`, not its values.

Here's one possible way to make (that part of) your code work:

```
for x in list:
    if x not in board.values():
        computermove = x 
        break
```

That's really all the help I can give you with the amount of code/information you've shown.